# Scala object: pass to or return from function

Tags: scala

Given class:

```
object Obj {...}
```

Is there a way to pass object to function or return object from function like this:

```
def f(x: Obj): Boolean
def g(x: Boolean): Obj
```

Both two examples causes CE (Compile Error).

I know that it's possible use object directly by name `Obj` in body of function f so first example mostly theoretical than practical. But for second example i can't see alternate ways.

Apparently both examples are 'antipatterns' and scala objects should not be applied such way.

Comment: Think about this, is `Obj` a type?

Comment: `object` is not a class, it's an instance of some class, in your case `Object` (or `AnyRef`).

Comment: Thanks! Of course it's an singleton object. But as you can see in answer below, the type of this object is `Obj.type` and using this syntax there is possible to pass it as parameter to fucntion and return it from fucntion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Obj.type`:

```
scala> object O
defined object O

scala> def f(o: O.type) = 42
f: (o: O.type)Int

scala> f(1)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: O.type
       f(1)
         ^

scala> f(O)
res1: Int = 42
```